# How do compilers implement C++ inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, compiler-construction, implementation

C++ supports inheritance.

But how is it implemented in the compiler?

Does the compiler copy and paste all the implementation from parent to child?

Comment: There's no **the** compiler, and each of them would have a different implementation (unlikely any of these will use s.th. like _'copy and paste'_).

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the copy and paste part, but removing that and the question would be too short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXTREMELY simplified, if we are talking about something like this:

```
class A 
{
    public:
       int func1() { do something; }
       int func2() { do something; }
 };

class B : public A
{
    public:
       int func2() { do somethign else; }
};

B b;

b.func1();
```

then what happens inside the compiler will be this (remember, this is VERY simplified, and the real compiler code will be a lot more complex, I'm sure):

```
 ... fname = "func1" from the source code ... 
 ... object = "b"; 
function fn;
while (!(fn = find_func(object, fname)))  
   object = parent_object(object);
if (fn)
  produce_call(fn); 
else
  print_error_not_found(fname);
```

If we are talking about virtual functions, then the compiler will produce a table which holds the address of the respective virtual function, and the table is generated for each class,  based on a similar principle of "find the function that exists in a this class or one of its parents).

[In the above, I've ignored the fact that one class can have more than one "parent" class - it doesn't change how things works, just that the code has to maintain a list or array of "more classes at the same level"]

Comment: There's more to inheritance than function calls, such as data members.  You have a good answer, but I believe it would be better if you discussed how data members are handled.

Answer (score 2):

Just like member variables, base classes cause a subobject to be embedded inside all instances of the derived class.  Member functions of the base class are not duplicated for the derived class, instead they are called on this subobject corresponding to the base class.

The compiler knows where this subobject is located relative to the full object, and will insert pointer arithmetic everywhere there is a cast (possibly implicit) between pointer (or reference) to derived and to base.  This includes the hidden `this`-pointer arguments passed to member functions of the base type.

Virtual inheritance is a little bit tricky, because the offset can be different depending on the most-derived type.  In that case, the compiler needs to store the offset as a variable inside the class instances so it can be looked up at runtime (just like pointers to virtual member functions, there might be another layer of indirection involved to save space).

Comment: But if I am to access a variable or call a function that belongs to the super class, how does the compiler know if that function or variable belongs to the super class and do the proper pointer arithmetic?

Comment: @ShaneHsu: When the compiler does name lookup, it finds out which class provided the definition of the function or variable.  Name lookup searches local variables, class members, base classes, namespace members, ... and then the compiler generates the proper code to access it depending on which kind it was.